# "How far did you make it to X ..."

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

Is this a valid construction? Example:

> How far did you make it to my apartment?

I ask because I only got [1](https://encrypted.google.com/search?biw=1855&bih=960&ei=6IW7Wp-5K4ur0gSmlrigDA&q=%22How%20far%20did%20you%20make%20it%20to%22&oq=%22How%20far%20did%20you%20make%20it%20to%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...5883.79845.0.80061.4.4.0.0.0.0.121.353.3j1.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.3.278...0i30k1j0i8i7i30k1.0.QiX90ZzE6gg) result on Google.

Update:

I also tried this: "How far to * did you make it." But got 0 results.

Comment: Perfectly fine, assuming you are expecting an answer similar to, "I made it halfway before my car broke down."

Comment: I disagree with EllieK; It sounds very strange to this US English speaker.  "How far did you make it?" is fine, and "Did you make it to my apartment?" is fine, but "to my apartment" implies *reaching* the destination.

Comment: @stangdon How about: "How far to my apartment did you make it?" or ""How far to my apartment did you reach?"

Comment: Your last version (How far to my apartment did you make it?) sounds most idiomatic to me.

Comment: @stangdon 'To' has many definitions.  A very common definition is, "Expressing motion in the direction of."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your phrasing is fine and will be understood.  The usage is very common.

> How far did you make it to my apartment?
>
> How long did you spend at the store?
>
> How much did you save for college?
>
> How fast did you run to the bank?

Those all work.